# ncurses: strange line formatting

Tags: c++, ncurses

I have this code to work with ncurses:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <cstdlib>

//char a='a';
int c=0;

bool ex = false;

void mva()
{
    std::cout << "Nothing here yet, move along." << std::endl;
}

void cho()
{
    std::cout << "Choose a valid option noob!" << std::endl;
}

void menu()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Choose an option" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4. About" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5. exit" << std::endl;
}

void pause()
{
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.ignore();
}

int main()
{
    initscr();
    //clear();
    refresh();
    //system("clear");
    while (ex != true)
    {
        menu();
        std::cin >> c;
        switch (c)
        {
            case 1:
                mva();
                pause();
                system("clear"); //unfortunately, there is no clean variant to this :(
            break;

            case 2:
                mva();
                pause();
            break;

            case 3:
                mva();
                pause();
            break;

            case 4:
                std::cout << "About" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Programmed by nnmjywg." << std::endl;
                pause();
            break;

            case 5:
                std::cout << "Press enter to exit" << std::endl;
                pause();
                ex = true;
            break;

            default:
                cho();
                pause();
            break;
        }
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

It should work normally, but I'm absolutely baffled when I see this strange line formatting. In addition to that, I also can't see what I enter (with `std::cin`)
[image: Strange line formatting]

Comment: Your posted code doesn't match your screenshot.

Comment: Like Jesper said, there's nothing in your code indicating printing those words.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's highly irrelevant. I want to know what's causing the strange formatting.

Comment: @DistantGraphics It's completely relevant since if the code your showing isn't the code that creates problem, that code is irrelevant to the question. You need to show the code that produces the problem you're asking about.

Comment: @Link but just for you, I added the WHOLE application as a pastebin.

Comment: @Distant Graphics "That's highly irrelevant" - no it is not. You post a screenshot showing behaviour you don't want along with code that could never have caused that output. How are we supposed to be able to help you based on that?

Comment: And post the code here directly. Code should never be linked to. If the link goes down, this question is near useless to future users.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Although your point is valid, I seriously doubt you want to sift through 96 lines of code to search for what I just showed. Nevertheless, you can look at my pastebin.

Comment: Don't link to code. Add code *in the question* as *text*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl See, the problem with that is that now I get the "your question is mostly code" error.

Comment: "I seriously doubt you want to sift through 96 lines of code" - that's why you should always construct a [mcve] before asking a question.

Comment: Are you compiling on the same machine you are running it? `'\n'` has a different meaning on *nix (LF) and Windows (CR/LF)?

Comment: @Aganju Yes. An ubuntu machine.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you for that useful insight.

Comment: You're welcome. Now please take it to heart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your program calls `initscr`, ncurses (actually **any** implementation of curses) initializes the terminal modes to allow printing carriage-return and line-feed ("newline") by themselves.  Printing a line-feed will not produce a carriage-return.

But iostream's **`endl`** is just a line-feed.  When you print to `cout` in that way, you'll see staircasing.

When using curses, `cout` and `cin` are not really useful.  Use `getch` (or `wgetch`) to read input.  Also, use the curses `echo` (or `noecho`) to control whether those echo the input which you give to **`getch`**.  The curses `echo` has no effect on `cin` (the terminal likewise has been set to not echo input, and curses knows when to echo).

Further reading:

- [Getch() incompatible with display function in linux c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943743/getch-incompatible-with-display-function-in-linux-c/40948904#40948904)

Comment: So if my program uses the standard std::cout, and std::endl, how to I uses ncurses to get non-blocking key input?

Comment: Look at [nodelay](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nodelay) and [timeout](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-timeout_wtimeout).