# Why is the ouput having unnecessary blank spaces preceeding every line?

Tags: c++, stdout, cout, ncurses

I wrote a C++ program to print every thing that user enters only after he presses an enter key, so until then he won't see what he has typed. Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char c, printText[10000];
    int key, i;

    initscr();
    refresh();
    noecho();

    while(1) {
        c = getch();
        key = c;        
        if( key == 10 ) {
            cout<< printText << endl;
            memset( printText, 0, sizeof(printText) );
            i=0;
        }
        else 
            printText[i++] = c;
     }

    endwin();
}
```

This code gives the following output:

[image: code output]

The output as per the requirement appears only after the user presses enter.But as you can see there are spaces that appears before each line starting from second line in the output and that is unwanted. I'am unable to understand why those spaces are occurring in the output and how should i avoid that? Please guide.

Comment: Use the ncurses functions for output. My guess is that `initscr` changes terminal settings such that `\n` only performs a line feed, not a carriage return.

Comment: Which platform or OS?  For example, Linux uses character 10 to represent a *newline* which is usually a carriage return and linefeed.  In Windows, you need the pair 13, 10 (carriage return and linefeed) to represent a *newline*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ncurses: strange line formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750687/ncurses-strange-line-formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing curses output and iostream output to the same device.  Use one or the other, otherwise you're going to get unpredictable weird things happening, like what you're seeing.